# Full text Search in firestore using algolia

Tags: android, node.js, full-text-search, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

Im trying to implement Full Text Search in Android Application that uses `Cloud firestore` as database, so in the documentation they said `firestore` does not support it and  go for `Algolia`(third party),Initially i tried using `algolia` search with some sample data and it works great.now i need to sync the data from `firestore` to algolia,im getting documentation only for realtime database and not for cloud `firestore`.
Documentation given by [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/3rd-party-service/firebase-algolia/) ,Documentation given by [google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search),
they have given node.js functions and im new to node.js. i cant find any tutorials related to firestore sync with algolia , so anyone knows where to start ? im able to upload data into firestore using node js, i need to export the data from firestore to algolia .i tried it using node.js as given by [google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) .this is the error im getting.i have tried changing the node versions , but no use.

```
    path.js:28
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'path', 'string');
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1244:7)
    at database (/Users/Desktop/Projects/FirebaseCLI/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:36)
    at Object.document (/Users/Desktop/Projects/FirebaseCLI/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Desktop/Projects/FirebaseCLI/functions/index.js:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

and this is the path of the document that im giving for document in firestore

```
    firestore exports.noteCreated = functions.firestore
  .document('note/{noteId}')
  .onCreate(event => {
    // Get an object representing the document
    // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
    console.log('New Note Created');
});
```

Comment: I think you should look into firebase functions. This way you can monitor the relevant nodes in the database, and sync them to Algolia.

Comment: Yes , i tried using the functions in the documentation , but im getting this error  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string

Comment: Hi @Dinesh. Can you provide som context for this error?

Comment: @DauleDK Hi , Please check the edit , i have posted the error

Comment: And where in the code do you use path?

Comment: Please check the edit @DauleDK

Comment: Have you tried this npm package? https://github.com/nayfin/algolia-firestore-sync

Comment: You can take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6x-ZJp-10)** where I have explained step by step, how you can achieve this with Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable not being set. I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/pull/200) to surface a more helpful error message here.

To set the environment variable, you can use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env): `cross-env GCLOUD_PROJECT=whatever`.